# Question about Hartshorne's notation on sheaves, difference between $\mathscr{F}|_U$ and $\mathscr{F}(U)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a question about Hartshorne's notation regarding sheaves. What is the difference between $\mathscr{F}|_U$ and $\mathscr{F}(U)$ where $U$ is an open set in the topological space $\text{sp}(X)$ with $X$ a scheme and $\mathscr{F}$ a sheaf on $X$? The former might be a sheaf on the relative topology on $U$ and the latter an algebraic structure such as a group or a ring or a module, but I am not completely sure. Can you help?

Comment: If this is still confusing/non-intuitive even though you've figured it out, it may help to keep in mind that $\mathscr F(U)$ is often referred to as the evaluation of the sheaf at $U$, while $\mathscr F|_U$ is referred to as the restriction of the sheaf to $U$, just as one does with functions.

Answer (score 1):

These things are of different types. If $\mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf of foos, then $\mathscr{F}(U)$ is a foo, and $\mathscr{F}|_U$ is a sheaf of foos on the topological space $U$.

Comment: So my above interpretation in the question was right, so this is what I conclude from your answer.

Comment: yes, that is right!